# Make rails new action respond with different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

How can I make my new action from a controller render a different view than new.html.erb. 
Can I make it render a partial, in which I'll have the form for example?

Thanks

Comment: try something like this `format.html { render "new_page", :layout => false  }`

Comment: or to render partial `render :partial => "some_other_page", :locals => { :new_object => @new_object }`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify explicitly which view to render as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-view) in the documentation.

```
def new
  render "another_view"
end
```

You can tell rails not to render layout, as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-layout-option).

```
def new
  render "another_view", layout: false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Can I make it render a partial, in which I'll have the form for example
```

Yes, You can. You can specify something like render partial in action.

```
render partial: 'new_partial'
```

or

```
render 'some_thing_else'
```